# Should advertising questions be off topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I just read: [when was the product placement introduced in sports?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/371/when-was-the-product-placement-introduced-in-sports) which asked about product placement in sports. This seems like a reach for being on topic. If it's on topic, are cheerleaders (not "cheer" as a gymnastic/dancing type sport, but scantily clad ladies on the side of a football field)? Would "what ballpark has the best hot dogs?" also be on topic?

It seems to me that this isn't talking about sports anymore, it's talking about the entertainment industry.

Answer (score 3):

sports history is on topic. However it still has to be a constructive question and it still has to be a useful question.

Sports is part of the entertainment industry. Its a huge business (several billion dollars a year). The business of sport is definitely on topic here, thus there are elements of that business that we will have to define our scope around. No the questions you mentioned probably aren't constructive, but there are good constructive questions centered around the business of sport that we should welcome with open arms.

Comment: I have to concur. Just because a given question may be poor for specific reasons does not mean every element of it is disallowed. Precedence should only be set for the criteria for which a question is closed, and not for a criteria that isn't either natural to the format or specifically discussed on meta.